# How to detect file download request

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, titanium-web-proxy

I have a situation where I need to block all file download request/response from web on the system which is running Titanium-Web-Proxy.
How can I identify all those requests/responses to block them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot able to find very simple.

Because every website using their own way of techniques. You need to do for individual website.

Check the Request.Method = "POST"

As far we detected few websites

Samples below :

// Dropbox uses chunks of octet-stream requests:

```
  if (url.Contains("/chunked_upload?") && url.Contains("chunk=0"))
  {
       //File Upload through this URL       
  }
```

// Yahoo uses savewithattachment method

```
 if (url.ToLower().Contains("savewithattachment"))
 {
 //File Upload through this URL  
 }
```

// Office365 Uses

```
 if (url.ToLower().Contains("createattachment"))
 {
 //File Upload through this URL  
 }
```